# Unable to run an angular app on kubernetes

Tags: angular, kubernetes, dockerfile, nginx-config

I have developed an angular app which is running fine in local. Then I have created a docker image which also runs fine in the docker env. Now I am trying to deploy the image as a service in Kubernetes cluster. It is showing the pod as running however I am unable to access the application. Initially I tried to run the app via `nodeport`. When it didn't work I tried using `loadbalancer` but it is always showing `EXTERNAL-IP` as pending.

Here are my details:

**nginx-custom.conf**

```
# Expires map
map $sent_http_content_type $expires {
    default                    off;
    text/html                  epoch;
    text/css                   max;
    application/json           max;
    application/javascript     max;
    ~image/                    max;
}

server {
  listen 4200;
  location / {
      root /usr/share/nginx/html;
      index index.html index.htm;
      try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html =404;
    }
  expires $expires;
  gzip  on;
}
```

**Dockerfile**

```
# Stage 1 , "build-step",
FROM node:12.16-alpine as build-step
RUN mkdir -p /app
WORKDIR /app
COPY package*.json /app/
RUN npm install
COPY . /app
RUN npm run build -- --output-path=./dist/out --configuration $configuration

# Stage 2
FROM nginx:1.17.1-alpine
COPY --from=build-step /app/dist/out/ /usr/share/nginx/html
COPY ./nginx-custom.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
```

**deployment.yaml**

```
--- 
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata: 
  labels: 
    app: login-ui
    version: v1
  name: login-ui
spec: 
  strategy: # Default, so usually not specified
    type: RollingUpdate
    rollingUpdate:
      maxSurge: 1 
      maxUnavailable: 25% 
  replicas: 1
  selector: 
    matchLabels: 
      app: login-ui
      version: v1
  template: 
    metadata: 
      labels: 
        app: login-ui
        version: v1

spec: 
  containers: 
    - image: "tagged-image"
      imagePullPolicy: Always
      name: login-ui
      ports: 
      - name: httpport
        containerPort: 4200
        #hostPort: 4200
```

**service.yaml**

```
--- 
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata: 
  labels: 
    app: login-ui
    version: v1
  name: login-ui
spec: 
  ports: 
    - name: http
      port: 4200
      protocol: TCP
  selector: 
    app: login-ui
    version: v1
  type: NodePort
```

**kubectl get pods**

```
NAME                                READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
login-ui-7445d644f6-n7d5m           1/1     Running   0          33m
```

**kubectl get svc**

```
NAME               TYPE           CLUSTER-IP      EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)          AGE
login-ui           NodePort       XX.XX.XX.XX     <none>        4200:31475/TCP   33m
```

**kubectl describe pod login-ui**

```
Events:
  Type    Reason     Age        From                Message
  ----    ------     ----       ----                -------
  Normal  Scheduled  <unknown>                      Successfully assigned default/login-ui-7445d644f6-n7d5m to node01-vm
  Normal  Pulling    38m        kubelet, node01-vm  Pulling image "tagged-image"
  Normal  Pulled     37m        kubelet, node01-vm  Successfully pulled image "tagged-image" in 5.401860205s
  Normal  Created    37m        kubelet, node01-vm  Created container login-ui
  Normal  Started    37m        kubelet, node01-vm  Started container login-ui
```

After that I am trying to hit the browser with:

```
http://"my-node-ip":4200/
```

but I am getting a unable to connect error. Also when I try to check the pod logs there are no logs there. Other pods are running fine there. I can see the logs for other pods and able to access the application from the browser.

Comment: check the firewall first and check you can really access the node or not

Comment: @HarshManvar : Hi ... Yes I can as already told .. there are other pods running there. And I can access them over the browser with the node ip.

Comment: You probably need the second port number from the `kubectl get service` output; try `http://any-k8s-node.example.com:31475`.  The `EXTERNAL-IP` field won't be filled in unless you have a LoadBalancer-type Service and your cluster knows how to populate that field (a public-cloud Kubernetes installation probably will; minikube probably won't).

Answer (score 1):

You need the second port number from the kubectl get service output.
Try:

```
http://any-k8s-node.example.com:31475
```

The `EXTERNAL-IP` field won't be filled in unless you have a `LoadBalancer` type of Service and your cluster knows how to populate that field (a public-cloud Kubernetes installation probably will; minikube probably won't).